# Automated BigTable backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

A *BigTable* table can be backed up through GCP for up to 30 days.
(https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/backups)

Is it possible to have a custom automatic backup policy?

i.e. **trigger automatic backups every X days & keep up to 3 copies at a time.**

Comment: You do this but need to do a bit of configuration yourself. We actually just published a blog on this today, so you're in luck! It should help walk you through the basics, but to set up 3 copies at a time might need a little bit of tweaking. Check it out here https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/scheduling-cloud-bigtable-backups

Comment: @BillyJacobson Wow the perfect timing :D Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the link provides a solution which involves the use of the following GCP Products:

- **Cloud Scheduler**: trigger tasks with a cron-based schedule
- **Cloud Pub/Sub**: pass the message request from Cloud Scheduler to Cloud Functions
- **Cloud Functions**: initiate an operation for creating a Cloud Bigtable backup
- Cloud Logging and Monitoring (optional).

Full guide can also be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/bigtable/scheduled-backups).

This is a good solution since you have a certain requirement that should be done with client libraries, because Big Table doesn't have an API that sets 3 copies at a time.

For normal use cases however, such as triggering automatic backups every X days, there's another solution such as calling the [`backups.create`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rest/v2/projects.instances.clusters.backups/create) directly by creating a Cloud Scheduler with HTTP similar to what's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062924/7031308).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another thought on a solution:

Instead of using three GCP Products, if you are already using k8s or GKE you can replace all this functionality with a k8s [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). Put the BigTable API calls in a container and deploy it on a schedule using the CronJob.

In my opinion, it is a simpler solution if you are already using kubernetes.